# How to connect the .net core console application to angular application?

Tags: .net, angular, postgresql, api, connection

I have created a .NET core console app and it's connected to the Postgres database and the connection is working. Now how can I connect this console app to the angular app to be able to perform CRUD operations?

Comment: I think you should disengage the console I/O and replace by some sort of webservice communication. Then, implement a simple SPA that can comuincate with that webservice. The webpage could then show the contents, pick up input from the user and such things

Answer (score 2):

I don't know how you're expecting that communication to work. Your angular App can't communicate with a console app. That cannot happen.

What I would recommend is converting your Console App to a Web API. Once it's a Web API, you will then have endpoints that you can call with the angular `HttpClient`.

Here's some documentation on how to go about using .NET Core and Angular

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/client-side/spa/angular?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio